# Language string failed to load: tls for first instance of phpmailer but second instance sent mail successfully

Tags: php, outlook, smtp, office365, phpmailer

I have tried to send two different mails using two different phpmailer instance.I am using same credentials and smtp informations but body and To address are different. Sometimes my first instance throws error not all the time. Here is my debug information while throwing error for first instance success for second instance send mail.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 MN2PR06CA0023.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 20 Apr 2020 11:38:10 +0000
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-MN2PR06CA0023.outlook.office365.com Hello [13.82.85.118] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed:
Language string failed to load: tls
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 MN2PR05CA0058.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 20 Apr 2020 11:38:21 +0000
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-MN2PR05CA0058.outlook.office365.com Hello [13.82.85.118] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-MN2PR05CA0058.outlook.office365.com Hello [13.82.85.118] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 Sender OK
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Start mail input; end with .
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.com> [Hostname=MA1PR01MB2377.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script is running correctly — it's just a debug output string that's having trouble, and the presence of that "Language string failed to load" error message means you are using a very old version of PHPMailer, so I suggest you [update it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. But i am having concern if it is version issue second mail also should not work right? but always my second mail is sent successfully. even my first mail also sent successfully sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue is because of office365 smtp server sometimes be slow especially while using tls and default timeout of 10 sec is not enough for that. After changing default timeout from 10 to 20 in phpmailer.php. it works like a charm.